# VBA Type Mismatch on Year Function as CountIfs criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a type mismatch error from the following code:

```
blattZFq3.Cells(month, siaw) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets(i).Range("AF10:AF290"), month, Year(Worksheets(i).Range("AE10:AE290")), minYear)
```

I'm guessing it's a problem with the second criteria, more specifically the `Year` function as criteria for a range since the code worked fine in  a previous version with just the first criteria and using `countif`.

`minYear` is declared as Variant and has been assigned the value of 2012 by a previous function.

Basically I want the cell in the range `blattZFq3` to contain the number of times a number matching  `month` occurs in a column, but only if the year of a date in the same row but different column matches `minYear`.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this function to the array: `Year(Worksheets(i).Range("AE10:AE290"))` as it's expecting a range for the second area to check.
Also, I would avoid using the word `Month` as a variable name, as it's also the name of a function.

You will have to write the function with 3 criteria to get around the restriction, or write a formula into the target area.

Function with 3 criteria:

```
blattZFq3.Cells(MyMonth, siaw) = _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets(i).Range("AF10:AF290"), MyMonth, _
    Worksheets(i).Range("AE10:AE290"), ">=" & DateSerial(minYear, 1, 1), _
    Worksheets(i).Range("AE10:AE290"), "<=" & DateSerial(minYear, 12, 31))
```

As a formula into the cell:

```
blattZFq3.Cells(MyMonth, siaw).Formula = _
    "=SUMPRODUCT(--(SheetName!AF10:AF290=" & MyMonth & ")," & _
    "--(YEAR(SheetName!AE10:AE290)=" & minYear & "))"
```

Comment: I solved it a little differently in the meantime...I added a function at the beginning of the sub that goes through the columns with the dates(4 in total) and writes the year number into 4 columns way to the right of the used portion. I can then just reference those columns just as I did with the month. Thanks for the tip about the variable name, I'll keep that in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Work with date sometimes is tricky. Are you using english version? 
You can try to write the same formula code in Excel and test it before you put it VBA. You can also try something like:

```
blattZFq3.Cells(month, siaw) = "=CONTIFS(.....)"
```